# Obtener datos especificos de Firebase Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, studio

Amigos buenas, espero me puedan ayudar, soy principiante y tengo problemas al obtener los datos de mi base de datos en firebase. Estoy utilizando un lector de codigos de barra, la idea es que el codigo obtenido en el escaneo, lo compare con los codigos ya registrados en la base de datos y entonces, obtener los datos respecto al codigo escaneado para mostrarlos en text view en una pantalla condicionada para aquello. El problema reside en que, al realizar el escaneo me muestra los datos del primer registro de la base de datos y no los datos con respecto al codigo escaneado. Adjunto pantallaso del primer registro en firebase.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al escanear el codigo de barras correspondiente al registro en la base de datos me muestra lo siguiente en mi pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al escanear un codigo de barras distinto al primer registro, me sale el primer registro de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recalco que quiero obtener la informacion solo de los datos del codigo escaneado. adjunto mi codigo:

```
    package com.example.mibo

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.mibo.databinding.ActivityMiBodegaBinding
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_mi_bodega.*

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class MiBodega : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMiBodegaBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mi_bodega)

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("productos")

        binding = ActivityMiBodegaBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.btnScanPro.setOnClickListener { (initScanner()) }
    }

    private fun initScanner() {
        val integrator = IntentIntegrator(this)
        integrator.setPrompt("Escaneando tu producto")
        integrator.initiateScan()
    }

    public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        val result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)


        if (result != null) {
            if (result.contents == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Escaneo cancelado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            } else {

                var tcodigo = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvCodigo)
                var srt = result.contents.toString()
                tcodigo.text = srt
                var getdata = object : ValueEventListener{
                    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                    }

                    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                        
                        var co = StringBuilder()
                        var tp = StringBuilder()
                        var mar = StringBuilder()
                        var des =  StringBuilder()
                        
                        for (i in p0.children ) {
                            
                            var codigo = i.child("codigo").getValue()
                            var tProducto1 = i.child("tipoProducto").getValue()
                            var marca1 = i.child("marca").getValue()
                            var descripcion1 = i.child("descripcion").getValue()
                            
                            co.append("${i.key} $codigo")
                            tp.append("${i.key} $tProducto1")
                            mar.append("${i.key} $marca1")
                            des.append("${i.key} $descripcion1")

                            if(codigo.toString()==result.contents){
                                binding.tvTipoProducto.setText(tp).toString()
                                binding.tvMarcaPro.setText(mar).toString()
                                binding.tvDescripPro.setText(des).toString()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                database.addValueEventListener(getdata)
                database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(getdata)
            }
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Producto no registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            
            }else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }

    }

}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, un abrazo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisa que el valor que devuelve el scaner es exactamente el valor del codigo de barra que escaneaste, puedes poner un Log o poner un breakpoint con el debugger.

convierte el codigo que obtuviste de la base de datos a cadena:

```
i.child("codigo").getValue().toString()
```

Usa los appends dentro del "if" que compara las cadenas de texto. De lo contrario esos valores se actualizan cada vez que pasen por cada registro.

Mueve el `.toString()` para llamarlo al establecer el texto en el textView:

```
binding.tvTipoProducto.setText(tp.toString())
```

Espero que sea de utilidad :D

Comment: Amigo, dame tu dirección para enviarte unas cervezas, te agradezco un montón tu ayuda, con esto avanzo mucho en mi proyecto, te mando un abrazo gigante. Tu solución funciona perfecta =)

Comment: @OscarTelloMuñoz puedes marcar como solución esta publicación si ayudo a solucionar la pregunta, revisa [tour], saludos.